# ng-show is not working with list in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to use `ng-show="emp"` with a checkbox bind it with `ng-model` inside a list but it is not working properly. Do you have any idea how it works?

HTML

```
 <fieldset id="field4">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="all" ng-click="selectall(all)" ng-disabled="self" /><label>Select All</label>  </td>

                <!--<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="clear" ng-click="clearall(clear)" ng-disabled="self" /> Clear all</td>-->

                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="self" ng-show="emp" /><label ng-show="emp">Self Service</label>   </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <br />

    <div class="wrapper">
        <fieldset id="field2">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="e in empdepts | filter : dept  | filter : code | filter : emp | groupBy:'dep_LDesc' ">
                    <td>
                        <label ng-click="showContent = !showContent"></label>
                        <details ng-open="showContent">
                            <summary>{{e[0].dep_LDesc}}</summary>
                            <ul ng-repeat="employee in e ">
                                <li ng-model="emp" ng-class="{'selected1':employee == selectedRow1}" ng-click="setClickedRow1(employee)"> {{employee.Sname}}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </details>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ng-model of the checkbox is binded to the scope variable "all" (ng-model="all"), why don't you do this?

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="self" ng-show="all" />
```

On the other hand, when something like this doesn't work, use a label/span to render the actual value of the variable you are using so you can easily see the actual value.

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually I will hide this element too, what i am trying to do is when the user click on element in the list the 2 check boxes appears, i tried <span ng-model="emp">{{employee.Sname}}</span> but doesnt work, do you suggest any idea,

Comment: <span ng-model> doesn't make sense as a span is like a label. You should try this to see the value: <span>{{emp}}</span>. Yo use ng-model to bind an html element (input for ex) to a scope property.

Comment: <ul ng-repeat="employee in e ">
                                    <li ng-model="emp" ng-class="{'selected1':employee == selectedRow1}" ng-click="setClickedRow1(employee)"> <span >{{employee.Sname}}</span> </li>
                                </ul>                                                                                   do you mean like this?

Comment: <li ng-model="emp" ...> also doesn't make sense. what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I am trying to hide these two check boxes in page load and appear when user click on an element inside the list <li>      i am trying to bind the <li> with the check boxes like ng-disabled, thanks

Comment: Hello , are you there

Comment: You can do ng-click in span inside <li> and set a scope variable to true or false depending on what you want to achieve. Then you bind that scope variable to ng-show in the other HTML element.

Comment: i tried several ways, kindly can you show me the code. thanks

Comment: Something like this: <li><span ng-click="emp = true;" >Click me</span></li>